# How to load an image (blobs) into Hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to load an image from hdfs into a table 
how can I load the image into HBase and retrieve it later?

Is there an examples that I can follow?

Answer (score 0):

[HBase Storage Module for Thumbor](https://github.com/dhardy92/thumbor_hbase) does something similar.
But please think twice before using HBase for BLOB storage, it's not the best choice.